Using .get() to pull a barcode from a customtkinter.CTkEntry box
This is part of a much larger project I'm working on, but I'm trying to break it down to the most basic question I could ask. How do I write the following line?
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
UPC_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, placeholder_text = "Barcode")

search = "SELECT Description FROM doitbest WHERE PrimaryUPC = '%s'" 
mycursor.execute(search, [UPC_entry.get()])
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
for x in myresult:
        print(x)

select_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="Search", command=search)

I'm trying to use Python to search my MySQL database by using CustomTkinter as a GUI. Long story short, I want to scan a barcode into a CTkEntry box (UPC_entry), press the CTkButton that I made, have it pull the barcode from the CTkEntry box, and then use that barcode to search my database for the relevant information. No matter how I try to write the above line, I keep getting errors. It all comes down to the last part "UPC_entry.get()". I don't know how to get the barcode out of the CTkEntry box (UPC_entry) and use that to search the database. If I replace UPC_entry.get() with a regular barcode (eg. 077922843671), it will come up with the correct information. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Is .get() even the right thing I should be using? I greatly appreciate any suggestions you guys might have.

Have you tried to print the result of your UPC_entry.get()?  What you have showed isn't really a minimal reproducible example so its difficult to offer relevant advice.  If you did something like search_value = UPC_entry.get() and then print(search_value) what prints? Maybe you have it formatted incorrectly and store an empty value.

@Rory I've updated the code in my post. I have tried to print the result of UPC_entry.get(), and I can't even seem to get that to print in the terminal. I don't know why. Ultimately though, I want it to print the results into the GUI and not just the terminal. Now when I enter an actual barcode that I know to be in the database, the terminal returns with "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable."

I see two problems in your example code: (1) Entry doesn't work like input() - it doesn't wait for user data. You need button (or other event) to execute code when user already put data in Entry. (2) command= needs Python funciton's name without () and later it will use () to run it - but you put SQL code. And this makes problem str because it tries to use () on your string - but string is not a Python function's name

You should not enclose the placeholder within quote.  Also post the error traceback as well.

command= needs Python function name without () but you put SQL query.
def my_function():
    #...code...

...CTkButton(..., command=my_function)  #  <- function's name without ()

When you press button then tkinter gets this function's name and it uses () to execute it. It can't use string as function's name.

You have to create function which runs SQL and assign this function to button.
# --- functions ---

def my_function():
    search = "SELECT Description FROM doitbest WHERE PrimaryUPC = '%s'" 
    mycursor.execute(search, [UPC_entry.get()])
    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
    for x in myresult:
            print(x)

# --- main ---

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
UPC_entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root, placeholder_text = "Barcode")

select_button = customtkinter.CTkButton(root, text="Search", command=my_function)  #  <- function's name without ()


BTW: this function's name without () is called callback (not only in Python but also in other languages - ie. in JavaScript)

You cannot put UPC_entry.get() directly in a SQL statement.  You need to use placeholder in the SQL statement and pass the required value when you call cursor.execute(...):
# use placeholder in the SQL statement, %s for MySQL
search = "SELECT Description FROM doitbest WHERE PrimaryUPC = %s"
# assume cursor is already created and pass a list/tuple containing the required value
cursor.execute(search, [UPC_entry.get()])


Thanks. I didn't know that .get() couldn't be use that way. I've updated my code in my original post, and when I try to enter a barcode into the Entry field this error pops up: "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable."
